# Template Parse error in HTML code

Tags: html, ionic2

I'm getting these errors when I run my Ionic 2 HTML code :
Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "form" " Submit [ERROR ->] 
Unexpected closing tag "ion-content"" Home Page</button> --> [ERROR ->] "

Here is my HTML code :

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-title (click)="showAlert()">
        Sign Up
    </ion-title>
    <form #userForm = "ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm.value)">
        <div>
          <ion-label color="primary">Enter Username</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" required #usernameRef="ngModel"  class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ngModel></ion-input>
          <div [hidden]=" usernameRef.valid || usernameRef.pristine ">
           Please enter username
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ion-label color="primary">Enter Password</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" required #passRef="ngModel"  class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ngModel></ion-input>
          <div [hidden]=" passRef.valid || passRef.pristine ">
           Please enter password
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
           <ion-label color="primary">Re-enter Password</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" required #repassRef="ngModel"  class="form-control" placeholder="Re-enter Password" ngModel></ion-input>
          <div [hidden]=" repassRef.valid || repassRef.pristine ">
           Please re-enter password
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
           <ion-label color="primary">Enter Email Address</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" required #emailRef="ngModel"  class="form-control" placeholder="example@email.com" ngModel></ion-input>
          <div [hidden]=" emailRef.valid || emailRef.pristine ">
           Please enter email
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
           <ion-label color="primary">Enter Phone Number</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" required #numRef="ngModel"  class="form-control" placeholder="+91-7022-51-074" ngModel></ion-input>
          <div [hidden]=" numRef.valid || numRef.pristine ">
           Please enter phone number
          </div>
        </div>
           <ion-label color="primary">Enter Country</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" required #conRef="ngModel"  class="form-control" placeholder="United States" ngModel></ion-input>
          <div [hidden]=" conRef.valid || conRef.pristine ">
           Please enter country
          </div>
        <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
     <button ion-button (click)="goBack()">Home Page</button> 
</ion-content>
```

Why am I getting that error ? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy! you forgot a div tag and add a div for a closing div

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-title (click)="showAlert()">
        Sign Up
    </ion-title>
    <form #userForm = "ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm.value)">
        <div>
          <ion-label color="primary">Enter Username</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" required #usernameRef="ngModel"  class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ngModel></ion-input>
          <div [hidden]=" usernameRef.valid || usernameRef.pristine ">
           Please enter username
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ion-label color="primary">Enter Password</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" required #passRef="ngModel"  class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ngModel></ion-input>
          <div [hidden]=" passRef.valid || passRef.pristine ">
           Please enter password
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
           <ion-label color="primary">Re-enter Password</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" required #repassRef="ngModel"  class="form-control" placeholder="Re-enter Password" ngModel></ion-input>
          <div [hidden]=" repassRef.valid || repassRef.pristine ">
           Please re-enter password
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
           <ion-label color="primary">Enter Email Address</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" required #emailRef="ngModel"  class="form-control" placeholder="example@email.com" ngModel></ion-input>
          <div [hidden]=" emailRef.valid || emailRef.pristine ">
           Please enter email
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
           <ion-label color="primary">Enter Phone Number</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" required #numRef="ngModel"  class="form-control" placeholder="+91-7022-51-074" ngModel></ion-input>
          <div [hidden]=" numRef.valid || numRef.pristine ">
           Please enter phone number
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
           <ion-label color="primary">Enter Country</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" required #conRef="ngModel"  class="form-control" placeholder="United States" ngModel></ion-input>
          <div [hidden]=" conRef.valid || conRef.pristine ">
           Please enter country
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
     <button ion-button (click)="goBack()">Home Page</button> 
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing an opening for one of your div's. Try this:

```
<div>
   <ion-label color="primary">Enter Country</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="text" required #conRef="ngModel"  class="form-control" placeholder="United States" ngModel></ion-input>
   <div [hidden]=" conRef.valid || conRef.pristine ">
        Please enter country
    </div>
 <div>
```